# Changing the files in webapps folder in CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have already pushed my application in cloudfoundry by pusing the .war file and the application is working fine. 
Now , the developer has made some changes and wants to make the following changes : 
1) Add the xyz.jar to the webapps/%app context%/web-inf/lib folder
2) Add the xyz.dtd to the webapps/%app_context% folder
3)  Replace the webapps/%app_context%/web-inf/web.xml file with the new web.xml file.

I think in cloudfoundry I cannot navigate to the webapps path , make the changes and restart tomcat.

Is there any way to make these changes in CloudFOundry.
Please Help.

Comment: This is not possible. once you shoot `cf push` command, it create `droplet` which is your compiled and staged app and `Diego Cell` stores this `droplet` in `blobstore` that make this immutable hence it can not be modified. Checkout this [link](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/how-applications-are-staged.html#stage-buildpack)

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned in the comments, you cannot update the files in a running application directly (actually this is not technically true, you can if you really, really want to but it's a very bad idea to do that).

Anyway, what you should do is simply push the application again. Take your new WAR file (the whole thing, not just the changed files), run `cf push` (same command as last time) and then wait for the app to stage and for the app instances to restart. At that point, your new changes will be live.

Hope that helps!